# How to get compress binary string from a row postgres

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, compression

Hello i have this code that produce a txt file with compress string that will be inserted into a postgres database

```
def test_insert():
    str_test = '4 1 2\n 2 4 5\n'.encode('utf8')
    cmpstr = zlib.compress(str_test)
    str_test_to_write = '\\x' + cmpstr.encode('hex_codec')

    with open('outfile.txt','w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(str(1) + '|'+ str_test_to_write + '\n')
        output_file.write(str(2) + '|'+ str_test_to_write + '\n')
```

Then i use the command copy to load the information into my table:

```
time cat outfile.txt |psql teste3 -c "\copy zstr(id,zstr) from stdout with delimiter '|'"
```

This is my table:

```
drop table if exists zstr; 
    create table zstr(
    id int, 
    zstr bytea, 
    primary key(id));
```

Then i want to select my strings but i'm getting this error:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> import zlib
>>> con = psycopg2.connect(host = 'X', database = 'Y', user = 'Z')
>>> con.autocommit = True
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('select * from zstr where id = 1')
>>> row = cur.fetchone()
>>> row
(1, <read-only buffer for 0x7fe19b75f270, size 41, offset 0 at 0x7fe196976f30>)
>>> a = str(row[1])
>>> q = zlib.decompress(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

So how can i get my strings?

The output i want:

```
'4 1 2\n 2 4 5\n'
```

Comment: Why are you zlib compressing strings?

Answer (score 2):

There is almost no reason to do this. PostgreSQL naturally compresses text, with LZ, if the value is larger than the TOAST_TUPLE_THRESHOLD. From the [docs on TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html)

> The TOAST management code is triggered only when a row value to be stored in a table is wider than TOAST_TUPLE_THRESHOLD bytes (normally 2 kB). **The TOAST code will compress and/or move field values out-of-line until the row value is shorter than TOAST_TUPLE_TARGET bytes (also normally 2 kB) or no more gains can be had.** During an UPDATE operation, values of unchanged fields are normally preserved as-is; so an UPDATE of a row with out-of-line values incurs no TOAST costs if none of the out-of-line values change.

It does this transparently for the user. Just store the text itself.

Comment: Oww i didn't know that. And can i set the threshold to less than 1 kb?

Comment: You can, however I would not. =) Unless you've got like millions (or billions) of rows and it really matters.

Comment: I have 100 millions of rows xD So what is your recommendation for the threshold? and why?

Comment: I would leave it alone. The trick, as a DBA, is to not retrieve data you don't use. Shy of that, it's just wasted hard drive space and a very hard core pre-optimization. How much waste space depends on the row size and the compression ratio. But if we assume 100% compression (ie, no size) the difference between 1kb and 2kb is 100GB over 100 million rows. However, it's certainly far less than that. Further, there is overhead in speed and space associated with TOAST.

Comment: Humm but what is the biggest problem if i modify my threshold to a crazy number like 5 bytes?

Comment: These are separate questions, we could spend all year going down the rabbit hole with hypotheticals about the internals.